# ¿Cómo importar una variable de una clase a una función interna de tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

**¡Hola Comunidad!**

Estoy desarrollando una GUI con `tkinter` que recibe ciertos parámetros de entrada para luego llamar a diversos módulos para que realicen determinada operación. He intentado desarrollar esta app aplicando algunos conceptos de la POO, sin embargo, debo admitir que tengo ciertas debilidades sobre esta metodología.

Para simplificar el código creé dos archivos, uno donde fluye la aplicación principal y otro que funciona como módulo. Este último realiza una determinada operación y almacena una variable. Esta última deseo capturarla en otra variable de tipo `tk.DoubleVar()`, la cual será la que se le muestre al usuario a través de la interfaz gráfica.

La GUI, propiamente dicha, queda definida como:

```
import tkinter as tk

from un_modulo import *  # Este será el módulo que realiza la operación 

class mi_app():

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.config(width=250, height=250)

        fm = tk.Frame(self.root)
        fm.pack()

        num1 = tk.DoubleVar()
        num2 = tk.DoubleVar()
        resul = tk.DoubleVar()
        def multiplicar():
            valores_usuario = Multiplicacion(num1.get(), num2.get())  # Esta clase pertenece a "un_modulo"
            valores_usuario.realizar_operacion()  # Este método pertenece a "un_modulo"
            resul.set(self.respuesta)  # La variable self.respuesta pertenece a "un_modulo"

        tk.Label(fm, text='Introduce dos valores para devolver su multiplicación').grid(columnspan=2)
        tk.Label(fm, text='Valor 1:').grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        tk.Label(fm, text='Valor 2:').grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        tk.Button(fm, text='¡Calcular!', command=multiplicar).grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='nsew')
        tk.Label(fm, text='Resultado=').grid(row=4, column=0)

        tk.Entry(fm, textvariable=num1, justify='right').grid(row=1, column=1)
        tk.Entry(fm, textvariable=num2, justify='right').grid(row=2, column=1)
        tk.Entry(fm, textvariable=resul, justify='right', state='readonly').grid(row=4, column=1)


    def mainloop(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ejemplo = mi_app()
    ejemplo.mainloop()
```

;mientras que el módulo está definido como:

```
class Multiplicacion():

    def __init__(self, num1, num2):

        self.num1 = num1
        self.num2 = num2

        self.respuesta = 0

    def realizar_operacion(self):
        self.respuesta = self.num1 * self.num2
```

Para ser más específico, la finalidad de este programa es que el usuario introduzca dos valores ("`num1`" y "`num2`"), al hacer click en el botón "calcular" el programa llame a una función interna "`multiplicar`", que una vez llamada cree un objeto de la clase "`Multiplicacion`" , el cual pertenece al módulo "`un_modulo`" y ejecute un método llamado "`realizar_operacion`", el cual modifica una variable dentro de la clase llamada "`self.respuesta`". Esta última es la que quiero mostrar al usuario en el `tk.Entry` correspondiente a la variable `resul`.

Debo acotar que este código es solamente con fines explicativos. Imaginemos que la operación que se realiza en el módulo es mucho más compleja que una simple multiplicación.

Finalmente, al ejecutar la app me aparece el típico error:

```
AttributeError: 'mi_app' object has no attribute 'respuesta'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self` dentro de un método de instancia hace siempre (en condiciones normales) referencia a la instancia de la propia clase a la que pertenece el método, si haces:

```
resul.set(self.respuesta)
```

`self` es la instancia a la que pertenece el método `__init__`, en tu caso un objeto de la clase `mi_app` y, lógicamente, dicha clase no tiene ningún atributo con ese nombre.

En vez de `self`, debes usar una referencia a la instancia de la clase `Multiplicar`, que en tu caso guardas en la variable local  `valores_usuario`:

```
resul.set(valores_usuario.respuesta)
```

Aclarar que `self` es solo una convención (podría llamarse como quisiéramos, aunque no es recomendable) para nombrar el objeto que todo método de instancia recibe de forma automática como primer argumento, que es la propia instancia de la clase.